# How to stop box shadow from merging into background color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I achieve this result, my box shadow is being overwritten by the below div's background color

[image]

```css
.mainBg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #f4f1f1;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 9vh;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
    background-color: #ffffff; width:100%">

</div>
<div class="mainBg">

</div>
```

Comment: `position:relative` to the first div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. To cause `box-shadow` shadows to get over a background, be it an image or a flat color/gradient, you need two properties:

- `z-index` to be higher than that of the background, in order to tell the navigator that this is on a higher layer than the background
- `position: relative` in order to cause the rendering engine to realize that it needs to render relative to the rest (and display the shadow)

```css
.mainBg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #f4f1f1;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 9vh; z-index: 1; position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-color: #ffffff; width:100%">

</div>
<div class="mainBg">

</div>
```

Comment: @TemaniAfif that's by specification correct, since `position: static` effectively is a directive to ignore all positioning requirements.

Answer (score 0):

hi what do you mean by saying that, you have assigned first div's height to 9vh and that's the problem, try some other units or decrease it by pixel...

also this is a tool that can help you there...

https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

Comment: Incorrect. His issue has nothing to do with `height`, it's a known issue with `box-shadow` and layered rendering.

Comment: yeah it's true... I admit.